# "Cycle found" with Spring Data Mongo 1.5

Tags: java, spring, spring-data, spring-data-mongodb

I have a project perfectly running with Spring Data MongoDB 1.4.2.
I tried to update to 1.5.0 and I get this error during autowiring (extract) :

> Caused by: org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.index.MongoPersistentEntityIndexResolver$CyclicPropertyReferenceException: **Found cycle for field 'rules' in type 'Filter' for path 'filter.rules'**
>     at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.index.MongoPersistentEntityIndexResolver$CycleGuard.protect(MongoPersistentEntityIndexResolver.java:370) ~[spring-data-mongodb-1.5.0.RELEASE.jar:na]
>     at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.index.MongoPersistentEntityIndexResolver$2.doWithPersistentProperty(MongoPersistentEntityIndexResolver.java:144) ~[spring-data-mongodb-1.5.0.RELEASE.jar:na]
>     at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.index.MongoPersistentEntityIndexResolver$2.doWithPersistentProperty(MongoPersistentEntityIndexResolver.java:138) ~[spring-data-mongodb-1.5.0.RELEASE.jar:na]
>     at org.springframework.data.mapping.model.BasicPersistentEntity.doWithProperties(BasicPersistentEntity.java:294) ~[spring-data-commons-1.8.0.RELEASE.jar:na]

I have a repository "RulesDAO" simply extending "MongoRepository". It manages an entity named "Rule". This entity has some basic fields and a "Filter" field. And this Filter class contains a list of Filter (which can be empty).

```
@Document(collection="rules")
public class Rule {

    @Id private String id;

    private String name;

    // other fields

    private Filter filter;

}

public class Filter {

    // for groups
    private String condition;

    private List<Filter> rules = new ArrayList<Filter>();


    // for query
    private String field;

    private String value;

}
```

("rules" is not a perfect name, but it has to be named this way for MVC binding)

So the Filter.rules property is interpreted as a cycle where it isn't ! (well in my understanding of the term "cycle")

Is it a bug in the release or is there a new "flag" for this usecase ?

Thanks

---

For the background story, the Filter class can be either a leaf or a node of a tree used to build complex Criteria, it is builded from the JSON of a jQuery plugin of mines http://mistic100.github.io/jQuery-QueryBuilder

Answer (score 13):

Your code is correct. That log message is just `INFO` level to tell you that there is potential cycle reference in your code.

You could ignore that annoying message by turning logger off. In case your are using Spring Boot, add this to your `application.properties` file:

`logging.level.org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.index=OFF`

Comment: With version 1.5.0 it was not just a log message, it was a blocking exception.

Comment: Ops.. I am using 1.6.3, so it's not a problem for me

Comment: Any chance you can provide additional information or links on fine-grained control of spring mongodb logging?

Answer (score 4):

The given types contain a strcuture potentially causing infinite loops while trying to resolve index information and/or reading values from the store.
During startup domain types as well as generic type information of Collections are inspected. This points out the cycle mentioned in the resulting error.

```
Rule -> Filter -> Filter.rules
          ^                |
          |                |
          +----------------+
```

Though the error should not prevent the container from starting - should only be printed to the log. Maybe you addtionally ran into [DATAMONGO-949](https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAMONGO-949) and want to give the current 1.5.1-SNAPSHOT a spin.

Please feel free to [open a ticket](https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAMONGO/).

Comment: I understand why my pattern might raise a warning, but I don't in the case of Thomas Gregory (although Spring thinks that "String dispositionCode" is type of DipositionCode...).

Doen'st seem the same issue

Comment: there's a problem when having 2 or more properties of same type within the root. Will be solved in 1.5.1 once it goes GA.

Comment: version 1.8.1.RELEASE and the problem is still there

Comment: version **spring-data-mongodb:1.10.1.RELEASE** and still warning the same.

in my case: `org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.index.MongoPersistentEntityIndexResolver$CyclicPropertyReferenceException: Found cycle for field 'iChronology' in type 'DateTime' for path 'fecha'`

does **spring-session-data-mongodb:1.3.0.RELEASE** has to be with this waring too?

Comment: I'm seeing this currently not just on startup but during REST API calls.  Executing the API twice gives me twice 30K of these lines.  Does this mean this inspection is running every time?

Answer (score 3):

**You are using:**
private List<Filter> rules = new ArrayList<Filter>();

**change this to:**
private List<?> child;

I was facing same problem but after using this the code is working fine without error.